# Excel odbc table date column not interacting properly with inequality in sumifs

Tags: excel, odbc, date-formatting, sumifs

I have a table called `some_table` on **Sheet2** which is loaded from an odbc connection to a Microsoft SQL Server database. In this table I have a numeric column `number_col` and a date column `date_col`. The latter has been formatted as a Date and the values appear in the form yyyy-mm-dd.

In **Sheet1** I have built a formula to aggregate `some_table[number_col]` over the rows where `some_table[date_col]` satisfy the property of being greater than or equal to the date 2019-09-29, which is stored in the cell **C4** of **Sheet1**:

```
=SUMIFS(some_table[number_col],some_table[date_col],">=" & C$4)
```

The formula returns a value of 0 (which is incorrect). If I change the `>=` to a `=` in the formula above, i.e.

```
=SUMIFS(some_table[number_col],some_table[date_col],"=" & C$4)
```

then the formula returns the value 12232 (which is correct).

From this I deduce that my syntax is correct, and that Excel is likely treating these values as strings for the purposes of matching, leading to successful matches on equality only.

I can confirm that the value in cell **C4** of **Sheet1** is a true date by converting it to a Number and getting back 43737.00, and both **C4** and `some_table[date_col]` are of type Date (display form yyyy-mm-dd). However, copy-pasting from `some_table[date_col]` to some other cell and converting to number does not change the pasted value. So I'm guessing the format of this column still isn't what I need it to be.

Have I correctly identified the root problem here? In either case, how can I get the column in this table to behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

data from an SQL database will have their own datatype, but after loading it into excel you should be able to use your formula without error (having tested this on my own file).

Does the formula work if you copy & paste the date and number columns to another sheet instead of having it loaded from the sql db? I would also try selecting the column as an array as well to test.